# Pythagorean triple test, yasm x64

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm using the yasm assembler on 64-bit Linux. The following program prints "False", while I think it should print "True":

```
section .data
    a   db  3
    b   db  4
    c   db  5
    succ    db  "True", 0x0A
    fail    db  "False", 0x0A

section .text
 global _start

_start:
    mov eax, [a]
    mov ebx, [b]
    mov ecx, [c]

    imul eax, eax   ;eax now contains a^2
    imul ebx, ebx   ;ebx now contains b^2
    imul ecx, ecx   ;ecx now contains c^2

    add  eax, ebx   ;eax now contains a^2 + b^2
    sub  eax, ecx   ;eax now contains (a^2 + b^2) - c^2
    cmp  eax, 0
    jne  failure

success:
    mov  eax, 1     ;write call
    mov  edi, 1     ;stdout
    mov  esi, succ
    mov  edx, 5     ;write 5 bytes
    syscall
    jmp end

failure:
    mov  eax, 1     ;write call
    mov  edi, 1     ;stdout
    mov  esi, fail
    mov  edx, 6     ;write 6 bytes
    syscall

end:
    mov  eax, 60    ;64-bit exit call
    mov  edi, 0
    syscall
```

Is there a problem with the flags? Apparently "not equal" is evaluating to true.

Answer (score 3):

Your variables are byte sized but you load 4 bytes from each. Use `movzx` to sign-extend, such as:

```
movzx eax, byte [a]
movzx ebx, byte [b]
movzx ecx, byte [c]
```

PS: learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that; I guess it would have helped me remember that registers are not initialized to zero.

Comment: It's irrelevant what they are initialized because you load 4 bytes. So `eax` gets all of `a`, `b` and `c` and the initial `T` from `True`, that is `eax=0x54050403` as a debugger can show you.